# gear motor can be used as generator

Tags: dc-motor, torque, mechanical-assembly, gear

I am in doubt with a motors operation,
I am not sure whether this question could be asked here,
I have a car wiper motor with two speed operation,It uses a PM dc motor with worm gear inside, so it is not possible to rotate the shaft when in stop condition so my question is there any way to act this motor as a generator??

please see the attached photo to see the gear mechanism of a wiper motor.

Thanks in advance[image]

If i gave a pwm input inorder to create a small torque,and if i rotate shaft in same direction which is already rotating is it possible to rotate and harness energy.

Comment: the worm drive has too much friction. if you were to remove the gears and find some other way to spin the motor it could be used as a generator.

Comment: hmm,me too is thinking about it.But toggling is a complicated task

Answer (score 2):

No.  Most worm drive mechanisms cannot be backdriven.

If that were not in the way, a brushed DC motor does typically function as a "lecture demo" generator when backdriven, perhaps to light an incandescent bulb, but harnessing one for useful purposes involves factors not detailed in your question.